# ML - Type Interface

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, type-inference, type-checking

From my recitation class  -

[image]

Can you please explain

- why does operator  $"+"$ signature is  $  int \rightarrow (int \rightarrow int)$ ?
- How does this graph is build  ?
- And what is mean $t=u \rightarrow s$  ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ML functions take a single argument. There are two common techniques to pass two arguments to a function.

- One is to create a pair (2-tuple) `p = (x, y)` and apply the function to the pair; the type of the function is then `('a * 'b) -> 'c`.
- The other approach is to make a function that takes one argument and returns a function that receives the second argument and does the work. This approach is what is done for `+` here and is called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). The function then has the type `'a -> ('b -> 'c)`. Since this is common, the `->` operator on types is chosen to be right-associative, so `'a -> ('b -> 'c)` can be written `'a -> 'b -> 'c`.

---

The graph, and the derivation on the left, present a simple approach to ML type inference by unification. The first steps are with the atomic subexpressions: `2 : int`, `+ : int -> (int -> int)`, and so on. Next, building on, we have the subexpression `plus 2`, which is an application; the types of `+` and `2` must be unified with $p \to q$ and $p$ for some $(p,q)$, which leads to $p = \mathrm{int} \to \mathrm{int}$ and $q = \mathrm{int}$ and the type of `(plus 2)` is $\mathrm{int}$. The derivation on the left shows the type inference for $(\lambda x. ((+ \: 2) \: x))$ from the types of $(+ \: 2)$ and $x$.

The graph represents the unification steps (with some trivial steps for atomic subexpressions omitted). Four variables $r$, $s$, $t$, $u$ are created to designate the type of each of the non-atomic subexpressions. The straight lines show the expression tree. The curvy line links the occurrence of the variable $x$ with its binding site.